# How to find function G(x), and make for every x, G(x) always returns fixed point for another function F(G(x))

Tags: optimization

I have a problem such that $F(G(x))=G(x)$, where $x$ is real numbers and I know that function $F$ can be computed if   value   $G(x)$ is given.  $F$ is a probability function.

I want to obtain a function form $G$ (or an algorithm G).

What is the problem? Is there any knowledge about "finding a function that gives fixed points of another given function"?

Comment: There are certainly algorithms for searching for fixed points, but there can’t be any good general answer because it would let you invert any function by adding a suitable linear function to it.